# Lazy filtering of a range?

Tags: scala

I was trying to calculate the first `x` prime numbers by using the following line of code:

```
(1 to Int.MaxValue).filter(is_prime _).take(x)
```

However, the program just didn't stop and I had to close it (I didn't want to wait until Int.MaxValue was reached). How could I rewrite this to work in normal time while mantaining the simplicity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range` will traverse the whole collection with filter. Try using a `view` instead:

```
(1 to Int.MaxValue).view.filter(is_prime _).take(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a Stream (or Iterator - see the comments below)

```
Stream.from(1).filter(is_prime).take(x)
```

Comment: Notice that DNA dropped the _ argument -- it is assumed if left out.

Comment: Also bear in mind that Stream keeps around the values it produces, so be careful about memory if x is large.

Comment: Depends on whether you hold a reference to the head of the Stream - see the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream). You could use `Iterator.from(n)` if that problem arises